# Need to filter mongo document containing array of object basis on bussines logic

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb

```
  {
    "id": 1,
    "holdDetails": [
      {
        "holdDescription": "COVERT_LOCK",
        "holdStatus": "CREATED"
      },
      {
        "holdDescription": "ALPH_LOCK",
        "holdStatus": "RESOLVED"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "holdDetails": [
      {
        "holdDescription": "ALPHA_LOCK",
        "holdStatus": "RESOLVED"
      },
      {
        "holdDescription": "BETA_LOCK",
        "holdStatus": "RESOLVED"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "holdDetails": [
      {
        "holdDescription": "ALPHA_LOCK",
        "holdStatus": "CREATED"
      },
      {
        "holdDescription": "BETA_LOCK",
        "holdStatus": "CREATED"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Now I want to filter this document basis on a condition that get all of those object
where all of the holdDetails is in RESOLVED holdStatus(ie COVERT_HOLD also in RESOLVED
holdStatus) or all of them are in RESOLVED
holdStatus except COVERT_LOCK in CREATED status

So post this condition result should be

```
  {
    "id": 1,
    "holdDetails": [
      {
        "holdDescription": "COVERT_LOCK",
        "holdStatus": "CREATED"
      },
      {
        "holdDescription": "ALPH_LOCK",
        "holdStatus": "RESOLVED"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "holdDetails": [
      {
        "holdDescription": "ALPHA_LOCK",
        "holdStatus": "RESOLVED"
      },
      {
        "holdDescription": "BETA_LOCK",
        "holdStatus": "RESOLVED"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

What should be the Query.class object created in java to produce such result?

Comment: So I want all of the object where all type of holdDescription are in RESOLVED holdStatus excluding the holdStatus of COVERT_LOCK.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$filter` with `$or` for this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$match: {
      $expr: {
        $eq: [
          {$size: "$holdDetails"},
          {$size: {
              $filter: {
                input: "$holdDetails",
                cond: {
                  $or: [
                    {$eq: ["$$this.holdStatus", "RESOLVED"]},
                    {$eq: ["$$this.holdDescription", "COVERT_LOCK"]}
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/-GC-oOXrJyY)

Comment: Hey @nimrod-serok can you help me to formulate this in a criteria query Java?

Comment: I'm not familiar with this

Comment: Issue with the query:::
The full response is:
{
    "ok" : 0.0,
    "errmsg" : "PlanExecutor error during aggregation :: caused by :: The argument to $size must be an array, but was of type: missing",
    "code" : 17124.0,
    "codeName" : "Location17124",
    "$clusterTime" : {
        "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1663235234, 1),
        "signature" : {
            "hash" : BinData(0, "YlOwObuxEf3L2dG41tkNDa1e8Rc="),
            "keyId" : NumberLong(7083587006063706114)
        }
    },
    "operationTime" : Timestamp(1663235234, 1)
}

Comment: Please provide a mongodb playground link with the case

Comment: This means that `holdDetails` is not an array (at least in one document), but on the sample data that you provided it is an array.

Comment: If you have documents without the field `holdDetails` use `$ifNull`

Comment: Found a solve, Criteria Query::
`            criteriaQuery.addCriteria(Criteria.where(HOLD_DETAILS)
                    .not().elemMatch(Criteria.where(HOLD_STATUS).nin(List.of(HOLD_LOCK_RESOLVED_STATUS))
                            .andOperator(Criteria.where(HOLD_DESCRIPTION).nin(List.of(MI_COVERT_HOLD)))));`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
Query query = Query.query(where("holdDetails.holdStatus").is("RESOLVED"));
```